# Verilog: use calculated variable as length or index of another variable

Tags: verilog

I need to expand and truncate variables a lot in my Verilog project. The issue is that the constraints for these operations are dynamically generated.

Example:

```
function sometruncation;
  input a, b, Z;
  integer x;
  begin
    x = a + b;
    somefunction = Z[x:0];
  end
endfunction
```

Another example for replication:

```
function somereplication;
  input a, b;
  integer x;
  begin
    x = a + b;
    somefunction = {x{1'b0}};
  end
endfunction
```

Vivado is now telling me that `'x' is not a constant`. I'm quite new to Verilog but according to my understanding I need to declare a `parameter` to get a kind of constant but this requires me to know the value beforehand, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For truncation, you can do a shift and mask operation.

```
somefunction = Z & ((2<<x)-1);
```

In your second example, replicating `1'b0` is unnecessary and doesn't accomplish anything. I find that the case is many other examples. You can always revert to a `for` loop if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't accomplish anything"? As I said, I'm pretty new to Verilog, but doesn't it mean a binary `0`?

Comment: I mean it's redundant. Every bit of `somefunction` will get to 0 because Verilog implicitly pads unsigned expressions with 0's.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Verilog is not a general-purpose programming language, it is a **hardware description** language. The hardware can't change its width on the fly...the width of bit vectors must be constant and known at compile time in order to synthesize a hardware implementation.

You will need to define the variables at their maximum possible width, then use masks to select the bits you need at any given moment. The mask vectors will also need to be defined with their maximum width. You can change the values of these bit vectors, but not their sizes.